# How to keep the lemma numbering same in different slides?

Tags: beamer, numbering

I am using beamer representation. I want to keep the number of the lemma's same through different slides. I do not want to renumber the same lemma in different slide

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Removes icon in bibliography
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\frame{\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{lemma}
  If $d$ is a $a$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
}

\frame{\frametitle{}
\begin{lemma}
  If $d$ is a $a$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
  wfmkrf
\end{proof}
}

\end{document}
```

see the same lemma getting different number

[image]

**Question :** How to keep the lemma number same in different slides?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX-SE! IMHO there is no need to use two slides, `\pause` suffices, and if you really want the title only on the first frame, use `\frametitle<1>{Outline}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1>{Outline}
\begin{lemma}
  If $d$ is a $a$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
\pause
\begin{proof}
  wfmkrf
\end{proof}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *really* want to remember the old value, here you go.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Removes icon in bibliography
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
\newcounter{oldlemma}
\newcounter{storethm}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{lemma}\label{lemma1}
  If $d$ is a $a$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
\setcounter{oldlemma}{\number\value{theorem}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Another lemma}
\begin{lemma}
  If $c$ is a $b$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\setcounter{storethm}{\number\value{theorem}}
\setcounter{theorem}{\numexpr\number\value{oldlemma}-1}
\begin{lemma}{\number\value{oldlemma}}
  If $d$ is a $a$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
  wfmkrf
\end{proof}
\setcounter{theorem}{\number\value{storethm}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Yet another lemma}
\begin{lemma}
  If $f$ is a $g$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I need this lemma in different slides also. Suppose i am recalling this lemma from some another slide in which I again want to show the statement of the lemma then what i will do?

Comment: @niceguy beamer has `\againframe` for precisely this.

Comment: @niceguy I added a version that also remembers the old value and reinstalls it.

Answer (score 0):

I would put both the lemma and the proof on one slide with overlays, and show the proof on the second subslide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{lemma}
  If $d$ is a $a$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
\onslide<2>{%
\begin{proof}
  wfmkrf
\end{proof}
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This resets the lemma number every time you start a new frame.

BTW, finding the counter names for lemma and frame was not easy.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not with my editor
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% I would rather not use XeLaTeX
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Removes icon in bibliography
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\counterwithin*{theorem}{framenumber}% added command

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\frame{\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{lemma}
  If $d$ is a $a$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
}

\frame{\frametitle{}
\setcounter{theorem}{0}
\begin{lemma}
  If $d$ is a $a$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
  wfmkrf
\end{proof}
}

\end{document}
```